# How to make fiddler less intrusive?

Tags: fiddler

Fiddler is a great tool for testing a wide variety of http scenarios. However Fiddler also blocks all kinds of traffic that it shouldn't. This intrusive behavior can be annoying and time consuming.

Is there a way to specify what Fiddler does and does not listen to? So I want to say only monitor and report on traffic going to localhost or www.google.com, everything else would be ignored.

Is that possible ?

Its just rather tedious to have to close fiddler whenever it blocks something it should not.

Comment: The only issue I've run into is when doing SSL captures. In this case it seems like some client programs *just won't silently accept* the intercept certificates. Which, at the end of the day, is understandable.

Comment: why the downvote ? Do you believe that my question did not show enough research effort ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiddler acts as a system proxy, so you can't have some traffic flow through it and some not, unless you can configure the client to not use the proxy for some connections.

You can use Fiddler's filter options to determine what is captured and shown in the sessions window.

However, what does it block ? I use Fiddler extensively, and have no issues with connections being blocked. Perhaps there is another solution than closing Fiddler.

Comment: Last night fiddler was blocking all my attempts to connect to a Sql Azure instance. It occasionally causes problems with spotify and every once in a while i'll find a page that won't load till I close Fiddler.

Comment: You probably meant to push the "Streaming" button in the toolbar. And you probably want to configure it to only decrypt HTTPS traffic from clients you care about, to sites you care about.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. I was just unclear on how to achieve it.

Comment: I disabled all of that and I still get errors from Spotify. I think they may attempt to detect if they're behind a proxy and keep it from working due to DRM concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when setting up Fiddler just now (Win7). My problem was that Fiddler (Fiddler2) was not detecting and using my corporate Proxy settings. I had to go and set them manually in **Fiddler Options > Gateway**

That is why all my non-local, non-intranet traffic was appearing to blackhole. Hope that helps.